# MySQL join table to itself based on row number returns no data

Tags: mysql, self-join

I've got a logs table with an ID column in it, and I want to do the following:

- Select the ID and row number
- Join the table to itself based on the row number

My objective is to get a specific row as well as the row before it. The SQL query below actually returns nothing. It's like it forgets the row number entirely. Joining on ID returns just fine.

Is there something that needs to be done in MySQL to support this kind of operation?

```
select * from 
    (select id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as 'row' 
        from logs, (select @rownum := 0) r order by id) a
join
    (select id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as 'row' 
        from logs, (select @rownum := 0) r order by id) b
on a.row = b.row;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your variable name in second query, using same variable in both queries can produce unexpected results

```
select * from 
    (select id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 as 'row' 
        from logs, (select @rownum := 0) r order by id) a
join
    (select id, @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 as 'row1' 
        from logs, (select @rownum1 := 0) r order by id) b
on a.row = b.row1;
```